# С чего начать писать векторный редактор?

Tags: графика

Пусть банальный, пусть простой, и пусть велосипед.
Интересно, все же для общего развития.

Comment: @Вячеслав1101, а векторный редактор - это тема курсовой сейчас такая?

Просто рядом еще один точно так же сформулированный вопрос.

Comment: нет. просто тема про графический редактор не интересно.
а вот с векторны редактором, все совсем иначе.

Answer (score 4):

1. Скачать Corel Draw, минут 5 посмотреть на него, помедитировать. Скачать исходники Inkscape, почитать, еще немного помедитировать.
2. Написать на бумаге или в Word документ с очень подробным описанием Вашего редактора и дать почитать другому человеку, связанному с векторной графикой. Если он поймет о чем речь можно продолжать дальше.
3. Выбрать парадигму программирования, язык и платформу. Допустим это будет ООП, С++ и x86
4. Спроектировать иерархию классов и компоновку исходных файлов.
5. Написать рабочий код для каждого класса и метода.
6. Скомпилировать.
7. Написать документацию для пользователей.
8. Продать 1 миллион копий и получить пятерку за курсовую.
9. PROFIT111!!!!!

Пункт 2 стоит очень хорошо проработать перед тем как начинать что-то писать. Люди рисующие в векторных редакторах с вероятностью 99% ничего не понимают в коде.

Пункт 3 является предельно важным решением.

Пункты 4,5,6,7 в процессе разработки на практике идут валом и перемешиваются друг с другом причудливым образом.

Answer (score 1):

Стволовым функционалом любого редактора (а значит и векторного) является пара функций Undo/Redo. Они как бы образуют собой ось времени, относительно которой происходит всё остальное - создаются, удаляются и трансформируются объекты, изменяются их свойства, происходит выделение и "развыделение" объектов, осуществляется перевод фокуса между объектами, изменяется масштаб отображения. В идеальном редакторе все эти вещи должны быть отменяемы. Причём каждая на оптимальную для данной операции глубину. Понятно, что для перевода фокуса и выделения достаточно небольшой глубины, чтобы можно было отменить сделанное только что. А вот для операций с объектами нужна большая глубина. В идеале - бесконечная. Причём весьма специфически организованная. Простейших операций для пошагового перемещения по оси времени недостаточно. Должна быть возможность вернуться к варианту, который "вроде был ещё не такой убогий, и это было где-то час назад", вдумчиво посмотреть на него, и, поняв, что здесь он ещё не совсем закончен, скакнуть минут на десять вперед.

Проектирование нужно начинать именно с этого. Функции Undo/Redo нужно сделать так, чтобы весь остальной функционал, который будет в редакторе, было легко с ними совместить.

Comment: бред. ты это сам придумал?

Comment: @Вячеслав1101, этот совет абсолютно правильный. 

Я бы добавил еще, что действительно хороший редактор (неважно текстовый, графический (векторный) и т.д.) должен быть еще и системой программирования со своим набором команд и языком для манипулирования ими.

Это Вам советы, если Вы хотите делать *хорошие* программы.

--

P.S.

Хотел посоветовать Вам почитать вопрос от @Shamov "Чем является программирование - ремеслом или искусством?" (и, конечно, его обсуждение), но к сожалению его кто-то удалил.

Comment: @avp Тот вопрос удалил не я сам, а цензура. Но в этом есть и положительный момент. Мне теперь не придётся писать свой вариант ответа.

Comment: @Shamov, а жаль. Интересная тема. 

А свой вариант ответа может все же опубликуете? 

(скажем в Мете, возможно цензура посмотрит на это более благосклонно)

Comment: @avp Я там даже не зарегистрирован. Посмотрел сейчас на темы, которые на первой странице. В тамошний формат этот вопрос вписывается ещё меньше.